# loading managed resources from c# and passing it to Native CPP code as a stream handle

Tags: c#, c++, interop, resources, assemblies

I have a file that I have embedded as a resource in a managed C# assembly.  I would like to pass the pointer to that resource and its size to some native code so it can extract it for me if needed.  Are there C# api's that give me the intptr of that embedded resource?

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard of C++ / CLI ? It's a language you can use to easily go back and forth between C# and C++.  You might want to give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Not without first loading the resource data. Perhaps an unmanaged resource would be more appropriate in this case?